# One account for some services

Tags: web-services, oauth, authorization

I cannot found some examples how to create a single account system for all services. For example, Google and Microsoft are use these structure. I have site and some services and I need to user registers at once and can use all service and site. But I never made this earlier and don't know even how to build so services.

Now I think make an auth service with OAuth 2 support. And my services connect to this service and authenticate in it. After the connected service gets a user ID and creates a local account with more details (which needed only for this service) and global user ID. But maybe someone know another solution. Just I don't sure that is the best solution.
P.S. I don't ask for examples of code or something else. I just need to understand the principle of operation of such related services as they interact.

Comment: Search for SSO (single sign on)

Comment: Thank you! I cannot find examples. Just I searched it by wrong tags.